# Phpmyadmin access denied

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Is your mysql service running ?

Comment: What colour is your WampManager icon. The `W` icon sitting in the system tray. If its not green then either Apache or MySQL has not started, probably MySQL in your case.

Comment: @sanketh yes it was running...@RiggsFolly it was always gray color changed from red one.... thanks for asking  by the way I got it after I did uninstall and remove wamp folder before re-installation taking place.... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is because your browser is getting an IPV6 version of the localhost ip address and the phpMyAdmin config is not setup to allow that address access.

Edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` and change it from :

**If you are using Apache 2.2.x**

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
</Directory>
```

**If you are using Apache 2.4.x**
Change it from

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```